# Does kotlin support making a class implementing an interface outside of its definition file?

Tags: kotlin

I see kotlin.List and kotlin.MutableList is implemented by java.util.ArrayList. But where did kotlin put this trick? Compiler or somewhere in stdlib?

If kotlin supports making a class implementing an interface outside of its definition file like the ArrayList case, it will be fascinated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, it is not supported.**

You are right, that is only a compiler trick. There are lots of magic applied to the collections to make them right. Fortunately it is not available to the devs. Special paragraph in the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types

Comment: Thank you. Pity kotlin doesn't support implementing interfaces externally. Why is that if I may ask?

Comment: I fail to even imagine such a thing. Could you provide an example of a language which does that?

Comment: OK. I guess I cannot. What I have in mind is like duck-typing. e.g. If you implement `close()` method for a class, you can use `use()` extension method. If I wanted to treat a thread pool like an IO resource, I would 'extend' the thread pool class, and implement the `close()` method (since I don't have the definition file).

Comment: @WinterYoung You can already do that with some aspects of Kotlin that are built-in.  For example for a `for (a in b)` style loop you can add a few extension methods to convince the compiler it is "like an iterator" without being one.  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops  ... You can add feature requests to [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) about other built-ins that would be nice to have.  Or about compiler plugin model that would allow new ones to be created.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Thank you for the extended explanation.

Comment: Swift supports externally implementing interfaces. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: Go too, in a certain way.